# Google Maps API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3ae_' of undefinedT.trigger

Tags: google-maps-api-3, typeerror

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>langganan</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="markercluster.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };
 
      var cluster = [];
 
  function load(lt,lg,zoom) {
   
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lg),
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
   
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      
    downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("nama");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("alamat");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("wilayah");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
   
 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      shadow: icon.shadow
      });
    
    
    cluster.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
           map.setZoom(17);
           map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
           infowindow.setContent("Kode Pelanggan   : "+markers[i].getAttribute("kode_pelanggan")+"<br/>"+
                  "Nama Pelanggan   : "+markers[i].getAttribute("nama")+"<br/>"+
                  "Alamat Pelanggan : "+markers[i].getAttribute("alamat")+"<br/>"+
                  "Wilayah          : "+markers[i].getAttribute("wilayah"));
           
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
          })(marker, i));
   
  } 
  
 
  var a=15; 
  var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, cluster,{
    maxZoom: a /*,
       
//       gridSize: size,
 //         styles: styles[style]
//  */
    }
  );   
  
  
      });
   }

    
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
 
 
  
 // google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');

 function info(x)
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(cluster[x],'click');
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
 }
function get(){
  var tempout;
  $.post('tampil.php',{ ambil: frm.ambil.value},
   
   function(output){
  
   var tampung = output.replace("[", "");
   tampung = tampung.replace("]", "");
   tampung = replaceAll('"',"",tampung);
   var kode = tampung.split(",");
 
   var latx  = kode[3];
   var lngx  = kode[4];
 
   load(latx,lngx,17); 
   
   info(kode[0]);
    
   
   $('#nama').html(output).show();
  }
   
  );
  

 }
                 
     
 
    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
  </head>

 <body onload=load(-5.162764,119.443118,13)>

 <form name="frm">
  <center><input type="text" id="ambil" name="ambil" value="">
  <input type="button"  id="Cari"value="Cari" onClick="get(); "/></br>
  
 <div id="nama"></div></center>
<a href="#" onclick="info(6);">Open Info Window</a>
 </form> 
 
 <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px" ></div></hr>
    
 
 </body>

</html>
```

I'm currently use a new system for my gis website and I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3ae_' of undefinedT.trigger 
@ main.js:18info @ map.php:112(anonymous function)
@ map.php:134jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.js:3143jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3255done @ jquery.js:9309jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback @ jquery.js:9713

Comment: Did you try using a version of the API other than the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)?

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pd3mywo6/1/)

Comment: this is my first time use google maps api n' im following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)...
can you tell me were in my script using another api...(sorry bad english)

Comment: ,the link "open window infow" was work ,but when i try to call " function get() " with inserting " info(kode[x]) " it show error....

Comment: here the [tampil.php](http://pastebin.com/CRapAiVi)